# I need to Semi permanently disable wifi on my tablet?

Tags: wi-fi

Heres the thing i work in a secure industry which recently changed its security policies to not allow for wifi capable devices.  i thought there may be a way to disable the wifi on a tablet in such a way to disable any output from the antenna. im not alien  to using software mods and could be encouraged to learn some new code for this.  the issue on the companies end is not loss of secure info but a worry of viral jamming of the company equipment which must remain online. also id like to be able to bring the wifi capability back but bricking is not completely out of the question but i wasnt sure that would even work with a tablet.  the test at the end of the day will come down when they use a scanner to scan the wifi spectrum.  so if i could technically shift the frequency the antenna is on or drastically lower its power output that would be the best bet im just not sure how to tackle the problem any help would be great. 
also im working with a nvidia shield k1 table currently running android 6.0 marshmallow

Thanks